# Wordpress: Returning every term of a specific taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to return every term of a specific taxonomy. I just need to add terms to an object which I can loop through. I've been working on this for while but don't seem to be able to get anywhere.

So for example I have the Taxonomy 'Brand', I have several terms within this taxonomy. How can I return every term under this taxonomy.

I have tried the following:

```
global $product

$test_value = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa-brands');
foreach ($test_value as $test_values) {
    echo $test_values->name;        
}
```

Only this shows an error int the log: `Unexpected T_Variable`

Comment: you can use this `echo $test_values['name']`

Comment: Make sure you have a ; after global $product

Comment: `global $product` === 'Unexpected T_Variable'. Should be 
`global $product;`

Comment: Also, use `get_terms()` if you need all terms from the specific taxonomy

Comment: Apologies for the obvious error on the $global. The function doesn't seem to return anything though. I don't seem be hitting the correct object. I'm just not entirely sure how I can access the correct objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this. The following code solved my issue:

```
$brand_terms = get_terms("pa_brand");
        print_r($brand_terms);

        foreach ($brand_terms as $term) {
            echo "\n" . $term->name . " " . $term->slug;
```